# Tables and graphs with SQL Server data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I work mainly with Excel with VBA macros in an institution, developing tools to chart, display and arrange data from large MS SQL Server tables and queries in several needed ways, getting data to be analyzed as needed.

I need to develop those solutions on a web interface, but I am a beginner on HTML, ASP, jQuery etc, and I won't be counting on a Visual Studio license nowhere soon.

Mainly I need to learn how to raw code on a simple IDE like Notepad++ or Sublime to connect, retrieve and display data from SQL Server, preferably using ASP and jQuery plugins.

I already searched on YouTube for tutorials but all of them requires previous knowledge, and I'm looking for a step-by-step coding tutorial or so with examples.

If anyone could give me hints from where to start or recommend some material specific for this type of task, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Look for tutorials on PHP, jQuery and Ajax. I don't think that a step-by-step tutorial to specifically do what you want does exist. Good luck.

Comment: @GSilva Why are you not looking forward to reporting tools ? They are built for creating visualizations. Some are free, some are paid.

Comment: This is a very broad problem, and I agree with Prabhat, it sounds like you should be using a reporting system. If you want something really substantial, consider Jasper Reports and Jasper Server, though note it's probably rather complex to learn in a rush. However if you really want to self-build, perhaps you could put together a simple system that produces data from a query, renders it to JSON, includes that in the JavaScript on a page, and then uses a graphing library to plot it in a web app. You can get started by using dummy data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things that you need to start (I assume you are familiar with HTML, or can learn a little HTML and JavaScript if you are not familiar).

**Tools**

1.] Visual Studio Express Edition (free version of Visual Studio)
[Link to Download](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-express/)

2.] Brackets(Another HTML Editor)

[Link to Download](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-express/)

3.] Atom (Another HTML Editor)

[Link to Download](https://atom.io/)

**Charts**

1.] Google Chart API - very easy to use, attractive looks

[Check it here](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

2.] Charts.js (Wonderful js library)

[Check here](http://www.chartjs.org/)

3.] CanvasJS (with lots of icon, bars and images in chart)

[check here](http://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/)

4.] HighChartJs (Performance, looks, easy to use)

[Check here](https://www.highcharts.com/)

I hope that all will be fine for a start, nothing much to do as a lot of samples are available on their official website.